# How to set up vpn-tunnel between 2 computers? (not working for me)

Tags: networking, vpn

I have some computers in my local network. I am trying to set up vpn connection between 2 of them.

I have this structure: router - 192.168.1.1, pc1 - 192.168.1.63, pc2 - 192.168.1.97.

**Settings on 192.168.1.97:**

I created new ip security policy:
[image]

I created 1 ip filter in it which contain 2 filters:
[image]

Also, I set up action filter:

[image]

Tunnel setting:

[image]

Authentication method:

[image]

**Settings on 192.168.1.63 are similar, but tunnel setting and ip filters are a bit differ:**

Ip filters:

[image]

Tunnel settings:

[image]

After that I am trying to ping pc .63 from .97. I am getting this result:

[image]

Ping from .63 to .97 is similar. Pockets sending and receiving without any problems. Why I don't get message about negotiating IP policies. I read somewhere, that firstly, pc's must negotiate policies (sharing keys etc).

So, both pc's can ping each other.

VPN policy, I'd created is **assigned**.

After I rebooted both pc's I am getting this result on **both** computers I am getting same results.

What I am doing wrong? My settings look correct, but I don't get message about policies, so there are no VPN tunnel between my computers.

Comment: @LDC3, same :) same as on screens. I can ping 63 from 93, but can't ping 93 from 63.

Comment: Do you have static or dynamic IP addresses assigned?

Comment: Static. Lol I just realized, that Ip is not 93, it is 97.... 1 moment, I will rewrite question a bit.

Comment: @LDC3 I'd just updated my question. Now Ip is correct: 97. Now, I don't get any messages about negotiating policies. Why? Also, I can ping one computer from another.

Comment: You still have a few 93 to change to 97 in the question and you should removed the old ping response. Since you can ping both ways, it just means that the computers can talk to each other, not that the VPN is configured correctly. What is the operating system on the computers?

Comment: @LDC3 93 has Win 8, 63 has Win 7. I updated full question now, sry :) Thank you. Yes, ping doesn't show, that VPN tunnel is working, but I read in some book, that if pc's starting work via vpn tunnel, message about negotiating policies should appear. Even ping pockets should be send via vpn, shouldn't they?

Comment: No, because you can ping any computer, such as www.google.com, which you haven't yet set up a VPN with. Since you have the correct IPs, my next suggestion is to read the various help sites on the internet. http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

Comment: No wait... I don't need VPN server. I need vpn tunnel between two points. It is another task with another result.

Comment: The link I posted is how to set up a VPN between computers using PPTP. Since the computers are on the same network, then you don't need to set up the router. But you still need to create a user and configure the port on both computers properly. Since I haven't set up a VPN before, it is a little beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I still think I have another case. I set up both computers to code/decode filtered pockets (I set up destination and source address of pockets) by some protocol with some key. This is the point of vpn tunnel. Yes, I can use vpn in another case, mentioned in link you posted, but it is another case.